# SweetAlert2 is not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, sweetalert2

I'm making website for db study.

I wanted to alert to user if user didn't input id and password in register page.

So I installed sweetalert2 by npm. But sweetalert2 doesn't work in route.js which connect user's ask and server.

```
var swal = require('sweetalert2');
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.id && !req.body.password){
        swal('WARNING','You must input both id and password!','error')
    }
    else{
        swal('COMPLETE','You registered your information!','success');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
})
```

How can I fix it?

---

I used .ejs file to use sweetalert2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <% include ../pages/head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% if(fail) { %>
    <% include ../partials/alert_login %>
    <% } %>
    <% include ../pages/login %>
  </body>
</html>
```

in login_connect.ejs includes when user fail login alert_login.ejs file and alert_login.ejs includes script tag of using swal of sweetalert2 module.

But It isn't work. What is the problem?
alert_login.ejs is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You are not our member!");
</script>
```